# R: Concatenate multiple columns into one and assign column name to each obs. as new variable

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, given the following data frame strucure:

```
Location   Date1   Date2   Date3
   a       value1  value2  value3
   b       value4  value5  value6
   c       value7  value8  value9
```

I would like to trasform the data frame as:

```
 Location  Values    Date
  a        value1   Date1
  a        value2   Date2
  a        value3   Date3
  b        value4   Date1
  b        value5   Date2
  ....
```

In order to collpse all columns into one I can use `stack {utils}`, but I cannot figure out how to assign the corresponding column name to each observation.

Comment: look for reshape from wide to long

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using `tidyr`...

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% gather(key=Date,value=Values,-Location)
```